# How to save togglebutton state android eclipse into mysql database

Tags: android, togglebutton

**Edited.**

now my app always stopped when i'm trying to open it. now i'm really confused because of this. anyone who can help me?

here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textview;
JSONObject json = null;
String str = "";
String GetId, GetPin1, GetPin2;
HttpResponse response;
Context context;
ProgressBar progressbar;
Button button;
ToggleButton tgl1, tgl2;
EditText EditText1, EditText2, EditText3;

String DataParseUrl = "http://192.168.0.114/smarthome/inputData.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new GetTextViewData(context).execute();

    GetDataFromEditText();
    SendDataToServer(GetId, GetPin1, GetPin2);

    handler.post(timedTask);

    progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tgl1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    tgl2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    // button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

// auto refresh every 5 seconds
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable timedTask = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new GetTextViewData(context).execute();
        handler.postDelayed(timedTask, 7000);
    }
};

// class for take value from url
private class GetTextViewData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Context context;

    public GetTextViewData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(
                "http://192.168.0.114/smarthome/getdata_1.php");

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
            json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            textview.setText(json.getString("sensor"));
            EditText1.setText(json.getString("pin1"));
            // EditText1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            EditText2.setText(json.getString("pin2"));
            // EditText2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (EditText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                // tgl1.setTextOff("Nyala");
                tgl1.setChecked(true);
            } else if (EditText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                // tgl1.setTextOn("Mati");
                tgl1.setChecked(false);

            }

            if (EditText2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                // tgl1.setTextOff("Nyala");
                tgl2.setChecked(true);
            } else if (EditText2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                // tgl1.setTextOn("Mati");
                tgl2.setChecked(false);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Hiding progress bar after done loading TextView.
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

// save value from android to database
public void GetDataFromEditText() {

    // convert from toggle into edittext
    tgl1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (tgl1.isChecked()) {
                EditText1.setText("1");
            } else {
                EditText1.setText("0");
            }
        }
    });

    // convert from toggle into edittext
    tgl2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (tgl2.isChecked()) {
                EditText2.setText("1");
            } else {
                EditText2.setText("0");
            }
        }
    });

    GetId = EditText3.getText().toString();
    GetPin1 = EditText1.getText().toString();
    GetPin2 = EditText2.getText().toString();
    // GetWebsite = editTextWebsite.getText().toString();

}

public void SendDataToServer(final String id, final String pin1,
        final String pin2) {
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String QuickId = id;
            String QuickPin1 = pin1;
            String QuickPin2 = pin2;
            // String QuickWebsite = website;

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", QuickId));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", QuickPin1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", QuickPin2));
            // nameValuePairs.add(new
            // BasicNameValuePair("website",QuickWebsite));

            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DataParseUrl);

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            return "Data Submit Successfully";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Submit Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(pin1, pin2);
}

// for back as exit
private Boolean exit = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exit) {
        finish(); // finish activity
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);

    }

}}
```

and here is my activity_main xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:textAlignment="center"
tools:context="com.example.ta.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Silahkan pilih apa yang akan dikontrol"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="20dp" >
</TextView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Lampu 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:textOff="Mati"
        android:textOn="Nyala" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Lampu 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:textOff="Mati"
        android:textOn="Nyala" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Suhu Ruangan"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="30"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ºC" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="2"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="1"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="3"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ta"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/iot_cloud"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and here is logcat error:

```
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857): java.lang.RuntimeException:         Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.ta/com.example.ta.MainActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.example.ta.MainActivity.GetDataFromEditText(MainActivity.java:174)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.example.ta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-26 15:06:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  ... 11 more
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Post whatever you have tried till now.

Comment: i don't have any idea how to write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this...

```
 toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener()
  {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked)
  {
    if(isChecked)
        // save into databse code 
    else
       // save into databse code 
   }
  });
```

use

```
   Switch toggleButton= ((Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_toggle));
```

Comment: thanks for your help sir. can you help my all code program please?

Comment: Sir, thank you very much. now my application is running.  

Cheers